# Manipulate navigation controller stack on other UITabbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Let's say I have a tab bar controller with 2 tabs.

The first tab has a navigation controller in it.

How do I, from the second tab, make the first tab's navigation controller to pop to its first view?

I've tried:

```
for (UIViewController *vc in self.tabBarController.viewControllers) {
    [vc.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UINavigationController *navController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Wouldn't your first line cause type incompatibility, since `[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]` returns a `UIViewController`, and you're assigning to a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: By the way, I've also tried `[navController.navigationController popToRoot..` with no effect.

Comment: Objective-C is a duck typed language. It's not static. The runtime doesn't care what is actually at index 0. If it responds to pop then it will pop. However, if you aren't sure there is a nav controller there, you can safe-guard from a crash by using if ([navController respondsToSelector:@selector(popToRootViewControllerAnimated:)])... I'm assigning to a UINavigationController so the compiler won't complain about it. You could also do id navController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; if you wished.

Comment: You're digging down to the navController's navController there. Just do [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I should have simply tried your suggestion before asking questions. It works. Thanks.